# Getting "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" but I have that id initiated

Tags: javascript, html

I have read on here that usually this problem comes up when the specific div isn't loaded yet or just isn't there. I have this code looping so even if it wasn't fully loaded the first time it will be by the next iteration. Also I for sure have a div with the id participants.

```
    <div id="participants">
         <div class="sectionhead wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">
            <span class="bigicon icon-user"></span>
            <h3>Participants<h3>
            <h4>Check out who has signed up already!</h4>
            <hr class="separetor">

            <div id"test" onload="updateVariables()">
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>


<script>
setInterval(function(){
    updateVariables();
},4000);
updateVariables = function() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var info = xmlhttp.responseText;
        console.log(info);
        var out = info.split("\n");
        console.log(out[1]);
        var outLen = out.length;
        for(x = 0; x < outLen; x++){
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += out[x];
          document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "<br>";
        }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","../php/tour.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because I don't know how and that isn't the issue it's the point that it doesn't like document.getElementById("test").innerHTML

Comment: The only explanation that I find is that your real html is different (you have the div `participants` wrapped in something) and it prevents it from really loading. Add a button on the page which does some test edits to the `"test".innerHTML` and see if it works

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also provide `console.log(info)`  output

Comment: @KirillSlatin ok I'll try that this is the full page if you wanted to check it out http://swaglifegaming.net/tournaments/

Comment: @Chris'o it just says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null Name:" every 4 seconds (because of my loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty simple. In your real page you have a simple typo mistake. Instead of

```
<div id"test" onload="updateVariables()">
```

You should have

```
<div id="test" onload="updateVariables()">
```

EDIT: the easiest way to locate such errors on your own is debugging. I consider at the moment that Chrome dev tools is the best option, however you can use dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd> of any browser, since this problem is simple. I will demonstrate an example on Chrome.

In console you will see errors happening. To the right of the error you can see a link to the place in sources where it happens. 
[image]
A click on [(index):247](http://(index):247) takes you there in debugger window. Where you can place a breakpoint. Once you hit the breakpoint you have very powerful tools provided by Chrome. You can add variables to watch list, you can execute any code in console, you can trace the DOM (Elements tab) at current moment.
[image]
The typo of interest can be easily located by copying the code you suppose is working to console `document.getElementById("test")`.

Now you start getting puzzled what the heck it returns `null` instead of a div. You go to elements tab and search for `test` by <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>. You find the text in html however after roaming around with beer you notice that the `id` is actually not defined due to wrong syntax

Comment: Just spotted the same thing :)

Comment: Unfortunately I was looking many times at it and only found by debugging real page :). Developer's attentiveness test

Comment: Well now I just feel silly! Thank you so much man. It's like trying to find the ketchup in the fridge!

Comment: Inclined to downvote for failing to describe how to find such typos on one's own.